# How to force TRESTRequest.ContentType to be ctAPPLICATION_JSON

Tags: rest, delphi

Drop a `TRESTClient`, `TRESTRequest` and `TRESTRepsonse` onto a form.

Set the `RESTClient.BaseURL`, `RESTRequest.Method` and `Resource`, also add a `"Content-Type"` header parameter with a value of `"application/json"`.

Add a JSON string using `RESTRequest.AddBody`, then view the `RESTRequest.ContentType`.

It shows `ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED` instead of `ctAPPLICATION_JSON`. This causes the server to return an error when `RESTRequest.Execute()` is run.

How do I force the request to use the correct content type when the property cannot be assigned to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at the `REST.Client` source code, if you specify the content type using this:

```
  AParameter := RESTRequest.Params.AddItem;
  AParameter.ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
  AParameter.name := 'Content-Type';
  AParameter.Value := 'application/json';
```

Instead of this:

```
  RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Then the `TRESTRequest.ContentType` property returns with the correct value, and this is the value used during `TRESTRequest.Execute`.

Another way to force the `TRESTRequest.ContentType` to be correct when using a body is to add the body text this way:

```
  RESTRequest.Body.Add(AJSONString, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: RESTRequest.AddParameter('Content-Type', 'application/json', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
client.AddParameter('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data', pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).